# double iteration over lists using for loops

Tags: python, list, for-loop

```
my_list = [12 , 23 , 8 , 6]
for i in range(len(my_list)):
   number = 5
   set1 = my_list[i] - number
   set2 = my_list[i+1] - number
```

given a list, What I am trying to do is subtract a set number (above I arbitrarily chose the number 5) from each number in my list and compare the preceding result from the previous result to see which result is smaller...after I have went through the entire list I would like to set a variable 'answer' to the result that gave the smallest number (so in my list's instance, it would be the last one, list[4] which should give me a result of 1)

the above code is where I am at so far, but have already run into an error that says my list index is out of range. any ideas on how to to fix this issue? also, If anybody could point me in the right direction as to how I will achieve the overall result, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When `i == len(list) - 1`, what do you expect `list[i+1]` to do? Also note that this seems pointless - given that the offset is always the same, the smallest result will be the one with the smallest starting point, so `min(my_list) - 5` would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need set2 since a for loop's job is to increment for you.

All you have to do is compare the current set1 result to see if it's smaller than the current minimum value, which we have assigned as the data found at list position[0], and put that in its place, this process is repeated until the for loop has passed through all the data in the list.

```
my_list = [12 , 23 , 8 , 6]
currentmin = my_list[0]
number = 5
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
       set1 = my_list[i] - number
       if set1<currentmin:
           currentmin=set1
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Your 'my_list' has length 4, if you call the '4+1'th index in your last line, you go out of range.